# Overriding spring application.properties via command line

Tags: spring-boot, gradlew, spring-boot-test

I was trying to change `my.url=test.com` in the application.properties from the command line while running gradlew `gradlew test -Drun.arguments="--my.url=myurl.com"'`. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: do you need to override the property during your tests or when you start the whole application with gradle? Could you post the unit/integration test you are testing?

Comment: During tests, it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying another properties file for tests, overwriting only the variables you need, i.e, *application-test.properties*.

With this *test* property file in hands, is possible to provide the correct profile for execution in a couple of different ways, such a simple argument *-Dspring.profiles.active=test* or the OS variable *SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE*, then Spring will fetch for specific app properties according to the profile specified.

Take a look at the original docs about [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-set-active-spring-profiles).

Comment: This does not address the question, which asks how to overload from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It could be better for you, to use @TestPropertySource annotation:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "my.url=myurl.com")
```

Also, if you want to run N tests with different properties - it could be better to have several profiles, for testing different environments

Comment: But the point is to configure it on the *command line*.